# How to change admin password of a Django application after deploying it on pivotal cloud foundry?

Tags: python, django, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have deployed a simple blog application( using tutorials and python buildpack) using Django and deployed it on Pivotal Cloud Foundry. But I am unable to log in using the same admin credentials after it is in the cloud. How can I change the admin superuser credentials?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

Comment: Assume you do not have command line access?

Comment: as i said i am able to change it in local, but its already on cloud and those dont seem to work. And not able to figure out how to change now.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you 
[This link in the docs may help you (changepassword)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#changepassword)

Or, perhaps you could simply create a new superuser with ./manage.py createsuperuser, and then change the password via the /admin/ panels.

Comment: But how do i link it with the CF commands for pivotal? I am able to do it on local but it's already deployed as an instance on the cloud.

Comment: Run `cf ssh <app> -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ‘’”`.  That will put you in the app container and you should be able to run Python scripts or other commands just like you'd do locally.

Comment: @DanielMikusa That's exactly what i needed. Thank you so much!